# Как вызвать переменную типа callable в php-cpp (со стороны C++)

Tags: php, c++

Как вызвать переменную типа callable в php-cpp (со стороны C++)? Очень надо. Очень важная задача.

передается так:
php_cpp_function(function(){});
В С++ функция принимает Php::Type::Callable.
Как потом переданный callback инициализировать?

Comment: `Php::call` не работает?

Comment: Проверю на днях, может в исходники загляну. Я в документации не видел и не вижу Php::call. Вижу вот такой пример: Php::call("md5", "myvalue"); Передается имя функции и аргумент. А я же в функцию передаю замыкание, без объявления функции. Меня в принципе устраивает вариант и с предварительным объявлением, но вопрос пока оставляю открытым. Спасибо.